# Get selected rows by checkbox selection?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In my column defs i have this:

```
 {
        headerName: 'All',
        field: 'all',
        headerCheckboxSelection: true,
        headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
        checkboxSelection: true,
        width: 40,
        maxWidth: 40,
        suppressFilter: true,
        cellStyle: params => {

          return { textAlign: 'center' }

        }
      },
```

But when i select by checkbox i dont get selected rows.Any suggestion how can i do that, to make select by checkbox same as row selection?

Im using this from ag grid documentation:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/

Comment: try **gridApi.getSelectedRows()**

Comment: but how can i trigger that event when user click checkbox ? on every click on checkbox i need to catch that and do something with that

Comment: try grid callback event - (rowSelected)="rowSelected()". Refer - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

Comment: thats it ... tnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ag-grid [Grid Events API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/)

> rowSelected   Row is selected or deselected.

Example given:

```
(rowSelected)="rowSelected()"
```